# How to pass arguments to the ListPageInteraction class?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I would like to change behavior of list page based on the menuitem which call is. I know I am able to call ListPage with different queries but I wan to go little further and have ListPage with different ListPageInteraction class or with ListPageInteraction class where I can have some arguments from menuitem which calls it. How can I do it?

I am adding range on ListPageQuery in ListPageInteraction class dynamically in initializeQuery method based on user which calls the list page.

I know I can have a duplicate of a ListPage with different ListPageInteraction assigned or I can artificially add some information to the _query but it does not seems right.

P.S.: Why there is no _args input?

Comment: See my answer, does it answer your question? If you are more specific about your requirement (what arguments do you want to pass for example), I will update my answer. Using the this.listpage().listPageArgs(), you should be able to get all properties that are on the menu item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is an args input, check the `SysListPageInteractionBase` class, in the `initializing` method the args object is retrieved:

```
this.setListPageType(this.listPage().listPageArgs());
```

You change the query based on this, check the `ReturnTableListPageInteraction.setModeledQueryName()` method for example:

```
switch (this.getListPageType())
{
    case ReturnTableListPageType::Main:
        // Don't change query
        break;

    case ReturnTableListPageType::Open:
        this.listPage().modeledQueryName(querystr(ReturnTableListPage_Open));
        break;
    [...]
}
```

Comment: this.listpage().listPageArgs() was what I was looking for.